# Is there a way to chain Result mapping and unwrapping?

Tags: rust

I have this code.

```
if let Ok(file) = env::var("CONF") {
    if let Ok(mut reader) = fs::File::open(&file) {
        if let Ok(conf) = Json::from_reader(&mut reader) {
            // do something with conf
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it less like a festive holiday tree and was thinking about chaining. Notice that each step in this chain produces another `Result`, so clearly this won't work (we get `Result` in `Result`).

```
let conf = env::var("CONF")
    .map(fs::File::open)
    .map(Json::from_reader);

// do something with conf
```

Also my error types differ for each step, which means I can't just replace `.map` with `.and_then`.

I think I'm looking for something that is similar to JavaScript's promises. That is, a promise returned from inside a promise unwraps the inner promise. The signature should probably be along the lines of:

```
impl<T, E> Result<T, E> {
    fn map_unwrap<F, U, D>(&self, op: F) -> Result<U, D>
        where F: FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, D>
}
```

Is there such a mechanism in Rust? Is there another way to get rid of my festive holiday tree?

Comment: There was a great article on this not too long ago actually: https://mgattozzi.com/posts/russian-dolls.html

Comment: Thanks! I check it out!

Comment: I use `try!()` macro

Comment: both `try!()` (and `?`-operator) have early returns on `Err`, i don't want that.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce, what is `Json` referring to? `serialize::json`? or serde?

Comment: `rustc_serialize::json`. i did't dare try the modern stuff :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there such a mechanism in Rust?

Yes — although not all in one shot like you've presented. Let's review your theoretical signature:

```
impl<T, E> Result<T, E> {
    fn map_unwrap<F, U, D>(&self, op: F) -> Result<U, D>
    where
        F: FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, D>,
    {}
}
```

This cannot work - assume that we start with an `Err` variant - how would this code know how to convert from `E` to `D`? Additionally, `&self` isn't appropriate for functions that want to convert types; those usually take `self`.

There are two components that you will need to combine:

1. [`Result::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then)

   ```
   impl<T, E> Result<T, E> {
       fn and_then<U, F>(self, op: F) -> Result<U, E>
       where
           F: FnOnce(T) -> Result<U, E>,
       {}
   }
   ```
2. [`Result::map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err)

   ```
   impl<T, E> Result<T, E> {
       fn map_err<F, O>(self, op: O) -> Result<T, F>
       where
           O: FnOnce(E) -> F,
       {}
   }
   ```

Then you will need a type that can represent both error types. I'll be lazy and use `Box<Error>`

Combined together, you need something like:

```
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() {
    let conf = env::var("CONF")
        .map_err(|e| Box::new(e) as Box<Error>)
        .and_then(|f| File::open(f).map_err(|e| Box::new(e) as Box<Error>));
}
```

Now each call converts the error value to a shared type, and the result is chainable with `and_then`. Presumably, your real code would create an error type that is suited to your problem, and then you would use that in the `map_err` call. I'd [implement `From`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29812530/155423), then you can have just:

```
let conf: Result<_, Box<Error>> = env::var("CONF")
    .map_err(Into::into)
    .and_then(|f| File::open(f).map_err(Into::into));
```

Comment: `Into::into` is a nice touch. Is there a "free" function like that to get a ref? `String` -> `&String`?

Comment: @MartinAlgesten I think you are looking for [`AsRef::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html), but it may not work in the case you want. You can't map an `Option<String>` to `Option<&str>`, for example, because it would be taking a reference to something that would then be dropped. There is `Option::as_ref` though.

Answer (score 5):

If you actually want to ignore the results as you are doing with `if let` you can use a macro like this:

```
macro_rules! iflet {
    ([$p:pat = $e:expr] $($rest:tt)*) => {
        if let $p = $e {
            iflet!($($rest)*);
        }
    };
    ($b:block) => {
        $b
    };
}


fn main() {
    iflet!([Ok(file) = env::var("CONF")]
           [Ok(mut reader) = File::open(&file)]
           [Ok(conf) = Json::from_reader(&mut reader)] {
        // do something with conf
    });
}
```

[Playground (without Json part)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Aenv%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Afs%3A%3AFile%3B%0A%0Amacro_rules!%20iflet%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(%5B%24p%3Apat%20%3D%20%24e%3Aexpr%5D%20%24(%24rest%3Att)*)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20let%20%24p%20%3D%20%24e%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20iflet!(%24(%24rest)*)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20(%24b%3Ablock)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24b%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20iflet!(%5BOk(file)%20%3D%20env%3A%3Avar(%22CONF%22)%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5BOk(mut%20reader)%20%3D%20File%3A%3Aopen(%26file)%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20something%20with%20reader%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0)

The macro is originally from [an answer I made to a similar question on `Option`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986141/how-to-group-option-assignments-in-rust/40987097#40987097), but it works with any `if let`. Though, with `Result` you often want to use the `Err` in some way, so I would usually lean towards [the approach explained by Shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41129287/3347227) or `?`/`try!`.

Comment: A macro is certainly a way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/) crate makes it possible to chain different error types together, and combined with the `?` operator you can express sequences of `Result`s very concisely. The downside is you need to return a `Result` from the function, so in certain cases you'll need to create a helper. If you only need the helper in one place though you can define it inside the calling function so it doesn't pollute the surrounding namespace.

Here's a simple [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bb183ac769df4606a2ea9171ec0084d) where I wanted to get a `usize` from an environment variable:

```rust
fn main() {
    fn env_int(key: &str) -> anyhow::Result<usize> {
        Ok(std::env::var(key)?.parse()?)
    }

    println!("{:?}", env_int("MISSING"));
    println!("{:?}", env_int("CARGO_PKG_VERSION"));
    println!("{:?}", env_int("PLAYGROUND_EDITION"));
}
```