# Does Rust 2018 support "if let" chaining?

Tags: rust

I'm parsing a vector of tokens, each of enum type. This means I get a lot of code like:

```
if v.len() >= 3 {
    if let Token::Type1(value1) = &v[0] {
        if let Token::Type2(value2) = &v[1] {
            if let Token::Type(value3) = &v[2] {
                return Parsed123(value1, value2, value3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty ugly - and I've worked out that I can do this to make it a little nicer:

```
if v.len() >= 3 {
    if let (Token::Type1(value1), Token::Type2(value2), Token::Type3(value3)) =
        (&v[0], &v[1], &v[2])
    {
        return Parsed123(value1, value2, value3);
    }
}
```

But honestly, its not much better.

However, there's some closed issues / RFCs for chaining these conditions and "if let" bits in what feels a lot more ergonomic way -- [Tracking issue for eRFC 2497 "if- and while-let-chains take 2"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53668) and [Support && in if let expressions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/929) -- this would let me write something like:

```
if v.len() >= 3 &&
    let Token::Type1(value1) = &v[0] && 
    let Token::Type2(value2) = &v[1] && 
    let Token::Type3(value3) = &v[2]
{
    return Parsed123(value1, value2, value3);
}
```

However, I can't seem to get this to compile in my copy of nightly Rust with `edition="2018"` (exact version is `1.32.0-nightly (653da4fd0 2018-11-08)`). So either I've got the syntax wrong or I've misinterpreted the RFCs / issues and this feature hasn't landed yet. Either way, I'd love some info on how this feature stands.

Comment: You might find [this library](https://crates.io/crates/if_chain) interesting.

Comment: @Michail That library looks awesome! I was wondering whether this could be achieved through macros. I figured it was worth its own answer and have added one. Hope that's OK with you.

Comment: How about `if let [Token::Type1(value1), Token::Type2(value2), Token::Type3(value3), ..] = v`?

Comment: @L.F. That is certainly an option now. This only landed in stable rust in 1.42.0 on 12 Mar 2020. You can see the release notes here. https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/03/12/Rust-1.42.html#subslice-patterns.

Comment: Oh that's right .. Time for me to learn some history.

Comment: Just to note, [let_chains](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/94927) that would allow this was due to be stabilized in Rust 1.64, but was then [reverted](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/100538) as it was not implemented correctly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[RFC #2497](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2497) has [not been implemented yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667). The [GitHub issue you linked](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53668) is only for describing how [to deal with the ambiguity](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2497-if-let-chains.md#rollout-plan-and-transitioning-to-rust-2018).

> To enable the second interpretation in the previous section a warning must be emitted in Rust 2015 informing the user that [...] will both become hard errors, in the first version of Rust where the 2018 edition is stable, without the let_chains features having been stabilized.

So no, you cannot use the syntax yet, but instead use tuples as a workaround, as you already did.

```
if v.len() >= 3 {
    if let (Token::Type1(value1), Token::Type2(value2), Token::Type3(value3)) =
        (&v[0], &v[1], &v[2])
    {
        return Parsed123(value1, value2, value3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Notably, when the RFC is implemented, **both** Rust 2015 and 2018 will support it.

Comment: Ah, so _`let` expressions in this position are experimental
see issue #53667 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667> for more information rustc(E0658)_ means "Sorry, not implemented"..

Answer (score 8):

While hellow is correct that RFC #2497 is not yet supported in 2018 (and 2015), I felt the `if_chain` library mentioned by Michail was worthy of an answer.

The [`if_chain`](https://docs.rs/if_chain) library provides a macro that transforms some code that is almost in the form of RFC #2497 into valid Rust.

You can write:

```
if_chain! {
    if v.len() >= 3;
    if let Token::Type1(value1) = &v[0]; 
    if let Token::Type2(value2) = &v[1]; 
    if let Token::Type3(value3) = &v[2];
    then {
        return Parsed123(value1, value2, value3);
    }
}
```

which the compiler treats as:

```
if v.len() >= 3 {
    if let Token::Type1(value1) = &v[0] {
        if let Token::Type2(value2) = &v[1] {
            if let Token::Type(value3) = &v[2] {
                return Parsed123(value1, value2, value3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments by L.F., in 2020 there is now another alternative. It still doesn't give us chained `if let`, but does allow us to match on slices - which is enough to make this example quite neat. The code could now be written as

```
if let [Token::Type1(value1), Token::Type2(value2), Token::Type3(value3), ..] = v {
   return Parsed123(value1, value2, value);
}
```