# How to use if let statement with conditions?

Tags: rust

I know it's possible to express AND logic between if let statement and a condition like this

```rust
if let (Some(a), true) = (b, c == d) {
    // do something
}
```

But what if I need an OR logic?

```rust
if let (Some(a)) = b /* || c == d */ {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

The only way I figure it out is as follows, but I think it's a little bit ugly as I have to write some code twice

```rust
if let (Some(a)) = b {
    // do something
} else if c == d {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Related: [Does Rust 2018 support "if let" chaining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235477/does-rust-2018-support-if-let-chaining)

Comment: Do you really have the same "do something" code in both cases? Does that code not use `a`, then?

Comment: If `a` is not used in the body you can just do `if b.is_some() || c == d { ... }`. If `a` _is_ used in the body then what should `a` be when `b` is `None` but `c == d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the same "do something" code in both cases then it must not use `a`. In that case you can use `is_some`:

```
if b.is_some() || c == d {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

In the more general case, you can use `matches!` to check if `b` matches a pattern without creating any bindings:

```
if matches!(b, Some(_)) || c == d {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```